# Custom Error Page for Over Quota Error in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

To fetch a 500 error I used webapp2 to show a custom error page : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#exceptions-in-the-wsgi-app.

This page is always shown when an error occurs. Even when there is an over_quota error and app.yaml is correctly configured.

How can i show a custom page for Quota_over Error ?

In app.yaml:-

```
error_handlers:
  - error_code: over_quota
    file: over_quota.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for quota over in App Engine is 503. So, you can create a handler that handles specifically the 503 error code.

Comment: No. The Status code for **OverQuotaError** is 500. It is clearly mentioned in the App engine Log. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/OverQuota.png

Comment: Hmmm, interesting since the latest information about this code is presented at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=961 that mentions that the old 403 error code was replaced by 503 for over quota, and 500 for anything else. Since then, no other change has been mentioned. In any case, in your configuration, have you verified that the location of the over_quota.html does not overlap with static file handler paths of your application?